# javascript asyncronous calls not waiting in chrome web applications (the code works indeed)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, google-chrome-app

With the following code

```
var counter = 0;
function loop-like() {

  do_something().then(function(){
    // waits until do_something() finishes

    counter++;
    if (counter > 100) {
      counter = 0;

      chrome.system.memory.getInfo(function(info) {
          console.log(info.availableCapacity);
          //if (info.availableCapacity < threshold) {
          if (1) {
              chrome.notifications.create('hey', {
                type: 'basic',
                iconUrl: 'icon-128.png',
                title: 'hey',
                message: 'message'
              },function() {
                //it supposedly waits until the notification is created/shown (?)
                loop-like();
              });
          } else
            loop-like();
      });

    } else
      loop-like();
  });
}

loop-like();
```

I am getting the console.log and the notification messages when everything is finished (they keep appearing for a while, as if the calls were still being made), whereas the intention was to halt everything until the notification is triggered and-I-guess-shown.

What's wrong?

EDIT: It does work, I was assuming it didn't but it does.

I am unsure about deleting it or not. If deleting it means that it will not be searchable then I think it would be useful not to.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you saying this isn't a problem anymore and you're unsure of whether or not to delete the question?

Comment: Yes. Now that you say it it doesn't make any sense. I find that the code might help someone that googles the keywords

Comment: The problem is this needs an answer. If the answer is "There was no problem" then the "problem" was solved in a way that will not be useful to future users. **but nothing is stopping you from leaving it here or even providing an answer.**